# Need space between two buttons on blog

Tags: html, css

I need help to create space between two buttons on my blog, one for previous post, one for next. Both buttons appear one next to another, i need to be in the right and left corner. This is the code for them:

```
                            <?php
                            $prev_post = get_previous_post();
                            if (!empty( $prev_post )): ?>

                                <a class="post-nav-prev" title="<?php _e('Previous post:', 'baskerville'); echo ' ' . esc_attr( get_the_title($prev_post) ); ?>" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $prev_post->ID ); ?>"><?php _e('Previous post', 'baskerville'); ?></a>

                            <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php
                            $next_post = get_next_post();
                            if (!empty( $next_post )): ?>

                        <a  class="post-nav-next"  title="<?php _e('Next post:', 'baskerville') ;  echo ' ' . esc_attr( get_the_title($next_post) ); ?>" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>"><?php _e('Next post', 'baskerville'); ?></a>

                        <?php endif; ?>

                            <?php edit_post_link( __('Edit post', 'baskerville')); ?>

                            <div class="clear"></div>
```

Comment: Show your CSS! We can't help you if you don't publish this.

Answer (score 0):

I honestly tried to run your code snippet locally, but just couldn't get it to work so I will do my best and help you achieve what you want.

But before I get started, make sure you don't post PHP snippets in a post that has nothing to do with PHP. If you were to only post the HTML code, it would have made things much easier.

So I see you have two a elements which you are using as buttons. You don't want them next to each other but "in the right and left corner" Although I'm not sure whether you mean the corners of the page or the corners of where those buttons might or might not be, here is how I would tackle this problem.

```css
#navigationControls{
  width:300px;
  height:20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="navigationControls">

<a class="post-nav-prev" title="test">Previous</a>
<a class="post-nav-next" style="float:right" title="test">Next</a>

</div>
```

By putting them in a container with a defined width, we can float the next button to the right of the container. You can modify the containers width to how big you want it to be.

Please let me know if my answer got you in the right direction and if you need any help!

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/78ebskh4r/  I want the two buttons to be at the 2 corners of the box. Sorry for posting unnecessary information, it's my first time trying to make a website and i really suck at it. Thank you for your time

Comment: Don't worry about it! You will get better overtime, and you need to add float:right to your next button like I did in my code snippet. It should just work if they are children of that box.

Comment: Could you tell me where exactly do I add it, after?
class="post-nav-next"  title="<?php _e('Next post:', 'baskerville') ;  echo ' ' . esc_attr( get_the_title($next_post) ); ?>" href="<?php echo get_permalink( $next_post->ID ); ?>"><?php _e('Next post', 'baskerville'); ?></a>

Comment: Do you have external CSS files or not?

Comment: I'm a total idiot when it comes to that.
What i have is a theme on a wordpress website, been changing it by deleting some of the code so I can remove the items I dont like and also used some plugins. Where can I check if I have external CSS files?

P.s. Really, really sorry to waste your time with my stupitidy.

Comment: No, seriously don't worry about it. And I am pretty sure your theme does have an external CSS file, I just have no idea where it might be. So I will keep things simple for you, although its not best practice to do things this way, but you could use inline styling to add float right on your next button. Check my code snippet in my post in a second, and tell me if that works for you!